# Problem using WebView and GluonFx / Gluion Mobile native build on Windows

Tags: javafx, gluonfx

I am trying to use a WebView within my JavaFX application built using Gluon Mobile. It works fine when running in IntelliJ using the gluonfx:runagent, and javafx:run targets. However, when I try to run the native application then I get the following runtime error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jfxwebkit in java.library.path
    at com.oracle.svm.core.jdk.NativeLibrarySupport.loadLibraryRelative(NativeLibrarySupport.java:132)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:47)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:166)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:54)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.lambda$static$0(WebPage.java:138)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:89)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.<clinit>(WebPage.java:137)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:854)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:839)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:275)
    at com.jdf.views.BullpenPresenter.onActionVideoPopout(BullpenPresenter.java:713)
```

I've added the javafx-web module to my POM file.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Other Settings:

- Java Version: 17
- <javafx.version>17.0.2</javafx.version>
- <attach.version>4.0.13</attach.version>
- <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.12</gluonfx.plugin.version
- <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
- Graalvm Version: graalvm-svm-java17-windows-gluon-22.0.0.3-Final

Any and all help appreciated.
Thanks,
Joshua

Comment: WebView is not supported for native image on Windows, see feature matrix in https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_platforms

Comment: @JoséPereda - Is this a planned enhancement for the future? If so ... any idea what the timeframe of that would be? - Thanks!

Comment: It is planned, and some work has already been done, but nothing conclusive. No timeframe at this time.